# PyGTK and Tree View

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I'm trying to add Tree View to my PyGTK app.

Here is how it looks in Glade:

[image]
[image]

And there is the main window code where I'm trying to add append some data to my Tree View:

```
import gettext
from gettext import gettext as _
gettext.textdomain('repository-notifier')

import gtk
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('repository_notifier')

from repository_notifier_lib import Window
from repository_notifier.AboutRepositoryNotifierDialog import AboutRepositoryNotifierDialog
from repository_notifier.PreferencesRepositoryNotifierDialog import PreferencesRepositoryNotifierDialog

# See repository_notifier_lib.Window.py for more details about how this class works
class RepositoryNotifierWindow(Window):
    __gtype_name__ = "RepositoryNotifierWindow"

    def finish_initializing(self, builder): # pylint: disable=E1002
        """Set up the main window"""
        super(RepositoryNotifierWindow, self).finish_initializing(builder)

        self.AboutDialog = AboutRepositoryNotifierDialog
        self.PreferencesDialog = PreferencesRepositoryNotifierDialog

        # Code for other initialization actions should be added here.
        self.builder.get_object('listLogModel').append([5])
        self.builder.get_object('listLogModel').append([6])
        self.builder.get_object('listLogModel').append([7])
```

But empty Tree View is what I get when I run the app:

[image]

Same happens when I add rows to Tree View from Glade.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add a `TreeViewColumn` under your `ListStore` with some `CellRenderer` to display the column you already have in the model.

To do that, select the `TreeView` widget and click on the `Edit` button. A dialog will be opened (similar to the one used to edit menus) so that you can add columns and renderers to the columns. After that, any changes in the model will be displayed in the treeview.

Comment: Great, now it works, but the problem is that now all cells are empty. Any idea? http://i44.tinypic.com/2eutxea.png

Comment: I guess the model already has data, so what yo're probably missing is the link between the renderer and the model column. Usually what you need to set `Text` in the renderer to the column number you're interested (other times, you're interested in colors, boolean values for checkboxes, etc.). If you wrote an alias for those columns in the model, they will be also displayed in the dropdown list for easier selection.

Comment: First of all, thanks for quick responses. I don't think I understand what you think, should I do something in Glade? In my TreeView, there is a link to model http://i.stack.imgur.com/xP3Ci.png (TreeView Model property), and in code I do self.builder.get_object('listLogModel').append([6]). So I'm populating the model which is binded to my TreeView. Sorry, but I'm newbie in Python and GTK. What am I missing?

Comment: Please have a look a this [blog entry](http://tadeboro.blogspot.com/2009/04/creatin-gtktreeview-with-glade-3.html). It contains detailed information with screenshots about what I was trying to explain in my response.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I see, picture tells a 1000 words. It works now.